# What is the cardinality of $L^p(\mathbb R)$, $1 \le p < \infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, cardinals

$L^2(\mathbb R)$ is isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb R)$ (which has the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ since there is an injection to the space of continuous functions which has the cardinality of $\mathbb R$), but what about different $1 \le p < \infty$?

What happens if we consider $L^p(O)$, where $O \subseteq \mathbb R$ is open?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, formally speaking $L^p(\Bbb R)$ is equivalence classes of functions whose $p$-th power is gives a finite measure. Right?

Comment: ..., where the equivalence relation is given by equality except on Lebesgue nullset. Of course, we want the $p$-th power of the _absolute value_ of the function to give a finite integral.

Comment: The cardinality is at least that of the continuum (why?). Furthermore, there is a dense countable subset. This should allow you to conclude that the cardinality is at most that of the continuum.

Comment: O.K., we have an injection from $\mathbb R$ to $L^p$ by the way of $x \mapsto x \mathbf 1_{[0, 1]}$, and further the truncated rational polynomials should be dense in $L^p$ since they are dense in the truncated continuous functions which are dense in $L^p$ by mollifying.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Where can I find a proof of 'separable normed spaces have at most cardinality of $\mathbb R$'?

Comment: @Cloudscape: More generally, this is true for separable metric spaces.  Sketch: consider the set $R^{\mathbb{N}}$ of all real sequences.  Show that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$.  Now if $\{e_n\}$ is a countable dense subset of a metric space $X$, consider the map $f : X \to\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with $f(x)_n = d(x, e_n)$.  Show that this is an injection.  (For any $x\in X $, there is a sequence $e_{n_k} \to x$, i.e. $d(e_{n_k}, x) \to 0$.  If $f(x) = f(y)$ then we also have $e_{n_k} \to y$ meaning $x=y$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PhoemueX gave [the answer above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384583/what-is-the-cardinality-of-lp-mathbb-r-1-le-p-infty#comment2819430_1384583) (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space#Cardinality; separable normed spaces have at most cardinality of $\mathbb R$). For a proof of that statement see [the comment of Nate Eldredge's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384583/what-is-the-cardinality-of-lp-mathbb-r-1-le-p-infty#comment2819484_1384583) to the post.