# What is the cardinality of $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: lp-spaces, cardinals

I know of this answer for $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ where $p < \infty$: [What is the cardinality of $L^p(\mathbb R)$, $1 \le p < \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384583/what-is-the-cardinality-of-lp-mathbb-r-1-le-p-infty)

But, what about $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, can we prove any result on its cardinality? I know there are non-separable Hilbert spaces which can have arbitrary large cardinalities.

Comment: I assume you're asking about the space $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, the set of equivalence classes, where two functions are equivalent when they are equal a. e.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|L^\infty(\Bbb R)|=c=|\Bbb R|$:

Since $t\mapsto\chi_{(t,\infty)}$ gives an injective map from $\Bbb R$ to $L^\infty(\Bbb R)$ it's clear that $|L^\infty(\Bbb R)|\ge c$.

Since $$L^\infty(\Bbb R)=\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z}L^\infty([n,n+1))$$and $$c^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\aleph_0}=c,$$it's enough to show $|L^\infty([0,1))|\le c$. But $L^\infty([0,1))\subset L^2([0,1))$.